# How can I make a write protected Ubuntu installation?

Tags: system-installation, usb, live-usb

I would like to install ubuntu to a flash [usb] stick (a live installation would work) with a few programs added (Arduino IDE, Xilinx Vivado, and possibly a couple others). As I've read online, running a normal installation on a stick would quickly break storage sections from excessive writes.
Hence, I would like this installation to only write to disk or ram. Then I wouldn't install new software or update ubuntu much on it.
Is this at all possible? Is it practical?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have been running a Full installation of Ubuntu from a flash drive for close to ten years now with no problems.

Most good flash drives have wear leveling and are good for at least 10000 writes.
For a 64GB flash drive lets do the math:

(64000 MB x 10000 writes) / (50 MB/s x 28000 s/8hourday) = 457 work days absolute minimum life span.